# Typescript: --outDir does not seem to work

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am using typescript in vs2015 and I have the following structure in my project:

```
in my wwwroot
           app - it containts some ts files
           lib
               spa - this is where I want all my compiled js to be
```

There is a tsconfig.json in my app directory with the following values:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../lib/spa"
  }
}
```

I have set up vs2015 to compile my ts files on save. But the compiled js files are generated in the same app dir, and not in the desired /lib/spa folder. Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript versions lower than 1.8 the **out** option does not work together with the **module** option.

You an check the issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1544).

In version 1.8 you will be able to use **out** when the module option is **amd** or **system**.

You can use the **typescript@next** version of TypeScript and make use of the feature now. To install it run:

```
$ npm install -g typescript@next
```