# Typescript: tsconfig.json outDir property does not work

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have the following `tsconfig.json`, and I want to have the transpiled output in `build/` folder

```
{
    "compileOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "noImplicitAny": "true",
        "removeComments": "true",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outDir": "build/"
    },
}
```

However it doesn't work. The only way I got it to work is to pass `outDir` as a flag to `tsc`.

I found one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920649/typescript-outdir-does-not-seem-to-work) which asked about the same issue I have. However I'm using typescript version 1.8.10. And I've tried the suggested solution there which I still couldn't get it to work.

Anyone know how I can have `tsc` read `outDir` property which is set in the `tsconfig.json` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option name is `compilerOptions` not `compileOptions`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "noImplicitAny": "true",
        "removeComments": "true",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outDir": "build/"
    },
}
```